# Eclipse Android migration to Android Studio lacking the androidTest folder

Tags: android, android-studio, android-testing, android-studio-import

After migrating a project from Eclipse to Android Studio, I'm unable to locate my androidTest folder which supposed to be generated when I create a new project on Android Studio. Are there any solution to solve it? I'm trying to do TDD yet there is no androidTest folder regardless on what I did. I created a tests folder like how Android Studio create the folder but it is not working.

Hierarchy:

```
- src
   - main
      - java
      - assets
      - rest
   - test
      - java
```

Edit: Adding my project structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create a `test` folder in the `/src` directory of your project and put your tests in there :-) The default was changed to that some time ago.

Also, in the Build Variants tab (lower left of the IDE window) you need to change the Test Artifact value to "Unit Tests".

EDIT:

Try adding this in the android{} section of your `build.gradle`:

```
sourceSets {
    androidTest.setRoot('src/test')
}
```

Comment: As a side note, consider getting Robolectric also, it is by far the best TDD framework for Android :)

Comment: How would you rate Robotium?

Also, do I need to restart android studio? I added a test folder in the /src directory, but it is not showing.

Comment: Clean the project and restart to ensure everything refreshes correctly. As for Robotium, it is good for unit testing, but is generally not as fast as Robolectric :-( And when you TDD, well, timing matters :-D

Comment: Sadly it doesn't work. This is my entire project hierarchy. Edited question to show hierarchy.